# How to create a range from two ranges in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two ranges, each containing a single cell (for example "A1" and "C3").

How do I get a new range containing all the cells between these two ("A1:C3")?

I tried this:

```
Set NewRange = Range(Range1.Address:Range2.Address)
```

Also how do I set a range in R1C1 format? I want to use something like Range("R1C2") instead of Range("A2").

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Like this?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
    Dim NewRng As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set rng1 = .Range("A1")
        Set rng2 = .Range("C3")

        Set NewRng = .Range(rng1.Address & ":" & rng2.Address)

        Debug.Print NewRng.Address
    End With
End Sub
```

Instead of R1C1 format use `Cells(r,c)`. That will give you more flexibility + control

So `Range("A2")` can be written as `Cells(2,1)`

Comment: Ugh just wrote exactly this, too slow! +1! :)

Answer (score 16):

You can set the a new range in various ways. Below are a few examples. To get R1C1 format - I personally find it easier entering the normal formula and then using VBA to extract the R1C1 format required. See the debug.print statements below.

```
Sub test()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim newRng As Range

    With Sheet1

        Set rng1 = .Range("A1")
        Set rng2 = .Range("C3")

        Debug.Print rng1.FormulaR1C1
        Debug.Print rng1.FormulaR1C1Local

        'Method1
        Set newRng = .Range(rng1, rng2)

        'method2
        Set newRng = .Range(rng1.Address, rng2.Address)

        'method3 (Only works if rng1 & rng2 are single cells
        Set newRng = .Range(rng1.Address & ":" & rng2.Address)

        'method4
        Set newRng = Union(rng1, rng2)


    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Union will not give you `$A$1:$C$3`. It will give you `$A$1,$C$3`

Comment: Yep - your right. Same as method 1. I was showing various ways of making ranges not all will be A1:C3. I was responding to the question in the title :)

Answer (score 16):

Method 4 is not the same as Method 1 when the ranges are not adjacent.

```
With Sheet1
Set rng1 = .Range("A1:A3")
Set rng2 = .Range("C1:C3")

'This combines the two separate ranges, so select A1, A2, A3, C1, C2, C3
set newRng = Union(rng1, rng2)

'This combines the two ranges in the same way as when using "A1:C3", 
'so including the cells from column B
set newRng = .Range(rng1, rng2)
```

Comment: This is a much more useful answer - I'm doing work for which I need to combine multiple ranges that can be anywhere on the worksheet (users can make multiple selections and they need to be tracked). Application.Union (and Application.Intersect!) will be very useful for some aspects of this!

Comment: I agree `UNION` ist the correct answer, if one would like to select multiple areas of cells!

Comment: If rng1 and rng2 belong to a worksheet other than the current one, it is important to use `rng1.parent.Range(rng1m rng2)` or as @user3484615 defined it using a `With`-Statement.

Answer (score 3):

It´s also possible something like:

```
    Dim newRange as Range
    Set newRange = Range("A1:A4,A7:A9,C1:D9")  'Three different regions grouped
    'or
    Set newRange = Range("A1:A4,A7:A9,C1:D9, D10:D11")  'Four different regions grouped.
    'or
    Set newRange = Range("A1:A4,A7:A9,C1:D9, D10:D11, ...")  'N different regions grouped.
```

Answer (score 2):

Put this in a module:

```
Private Function CombineRanges(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range) As Range

    Set CombineRanges = ActiveSheet.Range(rng1.Address & ":" & rng2.Address)

End Function
```

Use it like:

```
Dim NewRange As Range
Set NewRange  = CombineRanges(Range1, Range2)
```

Comment: This works but appears to have the same purpose as `Union()` but only works with 2 ranges