# In Excel VBA how do I save the selections I have made thorugh my Macro?

Tags: vba, excel

*I want to select every column that has the word "TEST" in the 5th row range, and then select the cells below down to a certain amount.
I have can find and select the range I want, I just cant have all my selections when I finish, and I want them so I can do some conditional formatting.*

```
Public Sub Macro1()

Dim n As Integer
n = 5

For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E5:UM5").Cells

    If InStr(1, "TEST", "TEST") Then
        Range(Cells(6, n), Cells(48, n)).Select
        n = n + 1
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

*Do you think a array would help me to keep the data to then select after?*

Answer (score 1):

The code below is modified from user **ooo** answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527725/how-to-create-a-range-from-2-ranges-in-vba) .

Is there a reason you need to select cells?  In vba you can do most things without actually selecting cells which makes it quicker and less prone to errors.

If you do need to select the cells I would build up the range and then select it all at once at the end.

Gordon

```
Sub test()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim newRng As Range

    With Sheet1

        Set rng1 = .Range("A1:A3")
        Set rng2 = .Range("C3:C5")

        Set newRng = Union(rng1, rng2)

        set rng2 = .range("E5:E7")

        set newRng = Union(newRng,rng2)
        newrng.select

    End With
End Sub
```

Applied to your code

```
Public Sub Macro1()

Dim n As Integer
dim rng as range
n = 5

For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E5:UM5").Cells

    If InStr(1, "TEST", "TEST") Then
        If rng Is Nothing Then 
            Set rng = Range(Cells(6, n), Cells(48, n)) 
        else
            set rng = union(rng, range(cells(6,n),cells(48,n)))
        end if
        n = n + 1
    End If    
Next

rng.select

End Sub
```

Comment: When i run this i end up selecting all the columns inbetween as well :(.

Comment: Yeah I didn't really read the code correctly,  The way you have instr set up in your code basically says find "test" in the word "test" which always returns true.  The answers from Sam and Tim are probably much cleaner answers and I would suggest those, although I think they both need small tweeks which I will suggest under their answers

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Sub Macro1()

Dim n As Integer, rng as Range, sht as WorkSheet

Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")

For Each c In sht.Range("E5:UM5").Cells

    If  c.value Like "*TEST*" Then

        If rng is nothing then      
            Set rng = c.offset(1,0).Resize(43,1)
        else
            Set rng = Application.union(rng, c.offset(1,0).Resize(43,1))
        end if

    End If

Next

rng.select

End Sub
```

Comment: I try to run this and get a error with the rng.select at the end, Runtime error ' 91' Object Variable or With Variable not set.

Comment: The error is caused by not finding any cells with the word "TEST" in it for the range your looking at.  See the bottom part of sam092s `if Not rng is Nothing then` code which has a check for this and would correct the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Sub Macro1()

Dim c As Range, rng As Range, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

For Each c In ws.Range("E5:UM5").Cells

    If InStr(c, "TEST") Then

        If rng Is Nothing Then
            Set rng = c
        Else
            Set rng = Application.Union(rng, c)
        End If

    End If

Next

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    rng.Select
    Debug.Print rng.Address
Else
    Debug.Print "Not found"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This code should work although it looks like he wanted to select a number of cells in the column so it would require either `c.offset` or `c.resize` to select the rest of the cells in the column

Comment: oh yeah I did miss that sentence. thanks for reminding. Tim's answer is correct