# define an array using 2 separate columns

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a table of data with many columns. I want to create an array with just the data from 2 of the columns. So far I've just been defining arrays like this.

```
finalrow = Sheet2.Range("A1").End(xlDown).row
finalcolumn = Sheet2.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).column
FTSE100 = Sheet2.Range("A1").Resize(finalrow, finalcolumn)
```

And I would really like to define it as a 2 dimensional array of the form

```
FTSE100 = "column A to finalrow" & "column G to finalrow"
```

Unfortunately, my google-fu hasn't turned up how to define an array using 2 non-adjacent data sets. Help  or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: you wan't 2 columns in a 1-dimensional array?? or do you mean a 2-dimensional array?

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified (since edited), 2-dimensional array

Comment: I'm researching this a little bit, and its not easy. But I can't think of any reason why you would want an array like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the two ranges independently, then use UNION to combine them.  Such as:

```
Set myRange = Union(columnARange, columnGRange)
```

More info available here: [How to create a range from 2 ranges in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527725/how-to-create-a-range-from-2-ranges-in-vba)

Comment: it doesn't seem to be working properly, it's throwing a "method or data member not found" when I try to use "myrange" to define the array

Comment: you probably have to initialize ("Dim") myRange before using it.

Comment: You specifically say you don't want a contiguous range -- your question asks about "non-adjacent" sets

Comment: Apologies, I've gone back and written it from scratch again and for some reason it's working this time. I don't know what I missed last time.

Thanks for your help.