# copying a range with excluding a range inside of it

Tags: vba, excel, copy

I have one question; I want to copy ranges between A1: P40 but i want to exlucede  A7:F40. Is that possible?

```
    Range("A1:P40").CopyPicture
```

Is there a way to exlude A7:F40 from the whole ?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527725/how-to-create-a-range-from-2-ranges-in-vba

Comment: So you want to make an el-shaped image of cell values?

Comment: yeah exactly because i Need that empty area

Comment: is it okay if the image has white space (in place of `A7:A40`)?

Comment: if you mean making that area blank and putting a text box inside no i dont want that. Best would be just having an Image which excludes that area so when i paste it then it won't effect the A7:F40 of the file which i paste my Picture.

Comment: okay - I see the problem now. you don't want to cover `A7:F40` in the sheet where you paste the picture. In that case, make two pictures. `A1:P6` and `G7:P40`. With the `.TopLeftCell` feature it should be easy to line them up correctly.

Comment: thanks:) could you write the code for that ? i get the logic but i dont know where i put it in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the two ranges separately and place the picture exactly where you want on the other sheet.

See this code, all tested.

```
Sub CopyPics()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

ws1.Range("A1:P6").CopyPicture
ws2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial

ws1.Range("G7:P40").CopyPicture
ws2.Range("G7").PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

if you want to paste a linked picture you can do this:

```
ws1.Range("A1:P6").Copy
ws2.Pictures.Paste(Link:=True).Select
With Selection
    .Top = 0
    .Left = ws2.Range("A1").Left
End With

ws1.Range("G7:P40").Copy
ws2.Pictures.Paste(Link:=True).Select
With Selection
    .Top = ws2.Range("G2:G7").Height
    .Left = ws2.Range("G7").Left
End With
```

Comment: what if i want to paste it to another workbooks worksheet?

Comment: @YigitTanverdi - just declare the workbook first. `Dim wb as Workbook | Set wb = Workbooks("myBook.xlsx")` Then set the `ws` to `wb.Worksheets("sheet2")`

Answer (score 0):

You can join multiple ranges via `Union`, but `.copyPicture` cant be used on something what is not rectangle or square.

Comment: why is this an answer if you will not actually solve the OP's problem?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - *'You can't get there from here.'* is an answer.