# How to select a range of cells using two variables in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to use:

```
    Set rng1 = .Range("A1")
    Set rng2 = .Range("C3")
```

as discussed in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527725/how-to-create-a-range-from-2-ranges-in-vba). The OP had cell A1 and cell C3 as two separate one-cell ranges. He asked how to change the range so that all cells in between them are also included in a new bigger range. My issue is similar, but my cell range changes with each new scenario. Example #1 start date in cell D1 and end date in cell Y1, new range is D1:Y1; or example #2 start date in cell B1 and end date in cell AZ1, new range is B1:AZ1. How can I change the above code so that a variable can be used instead of a static range?

Comment: Do you know you can do this without VBA, with conditional formatting?

Comment: Yes, but this idea has other applications in my model such as writing a formula for a set of conditions and after that range another set of conditions.

Comment: Also that seems to be possible without VBA, with in-cell formulas.

Comment: Your question is unclear. If `s` is a string variable which holds a value like "A1" then `Range(s)` works exactly like `Range("A1")`. By itself, that answers your question, though I suspect that you have larger questions about how VBA works.

Comment: @John Coleman, I just rephrased my question in my original post. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How do you know in which cells the start and end dates will be?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood the question correctly. So, please have a look at the following and let me know if this resolves your "problem":

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub tmpTest()

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rngComposite As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set rng1 = .Range("A1")
    Set rng2 = .Range("C3")
    Set rngComposite = .Range(rng1, rng2)
    Debug.Print rngComposite.Address
End With

End Sub
```

Essentially, the range `.Range(rng1, rng2)` is as dynamic as the underlying ranges and will change each time that `rng1` or `rng2` changes.

Comment: Ralph, thanks much. I just ran your code within my code. In your example, won't rng1 always be cell A1? How do I make A1 a variable cell address instead? The range changes in each scenario I run.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding the above code? .Range("C3") is always cell reference C3, correct? How can C3 be a variable that I can declare in a previous step. Thanks.

Comment: `rng2` is the variable not `C3`. So, yes, above I am setting `rng2` to `C3`. But the good think about **variables** is that you can change them. You can change it to refer to `D1` or whatever you want. Still, it does not matter which range you want. At some point in your code you will have to write what you want (`C3` or `D1` or whatever else).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a brute-force solution that builds the composite range using strings:

```
rngTxt1 = Cells(Cost_Row, Cost_PnCol).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, columnabsolute:=False)
rngTxt2 = Cells(Cost_LastRow, Cost_PnCol).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, columnabsolute:=False)

Worksheets(Cost_SheetName).Range(rngTxt1 & ":" & rngTxt2).ClearFormats
```