# Type Mismatch: Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

My program is erroring on this line with a 'Type Mismatch' error. I am trying to copy a range of cells onto a new sheet. I checked the dimensions of the old and new ranges and they are the same, so that is not the problem.

```
CSht.Range(CSht.Cells(2, 1), CSht.Cells(LstRow2, LstCol2)).Copy Destination:=Sheets(WS_New).Range(WS_New.Cells(1, 1), WS_New.Cells(LstRow2 - 1, LstCol2))
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527725/how-to-create-a-range-from-2-ranges-in-vba

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it as,

```
With csht
    .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(LstRow2, LstCol2)).Copy _
      Destination:=WS_New.Range(WS_New.Cells(1, 1), WS_New.Cells(LstRow2 - 1, LstCol2))
End With
```

In the destination, you had both `Sheets(WS_New).Range` and `WS_New.Cells`. It is one or the other; either `WS_New` is the name of the worksheet as a string or the worksheet as an object, not a mashup of methods.

BTW, you really only need the top left cell for a paste. That could have just as easily been,

```
With csht
    .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(LstRow2, LstCol2)).Copy _
      Destination:=WS_New.Cells(1, 1)
End With
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks so much. So when WS_New is in () it is referring to it as a string and WS_New.Cells is the object?

Comment: Yes, if you `Set WS_New = Worksheets("Sheet1")` use the first one like `WS_New.Cells`. If you `Dim WS_New as String: WS_New = "Sheet1"` then you use the second one like `Sheets(WS_New).Range`.

Comment: `Sheets()` is a reference to a collection of all worksheets in `ActiveWorkbook`, so the number or name in the `WS_New` variable is supposed to select one of them. Use `Option Explicit` at the top of your code module to minimize this type of error.

Answer (score 1):

To make a Range from 2 Ranges: [How to create a range from 2 ranges in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527725/how-to-create-a-range-from-2-ranges-in-vba)

```
CSht.Range(CSht.Cells(2, 1).address & ":" & CSht.Cells(LstRow2, LstCol2).address).Copy Destination:=Sheets(WS_New).Range(WS_New.Cells(1, 1).address & ":" & WS_New.Cells(LstRow2 - 1, LstCol2).address)
```

Note that Sheets(WS_New) will only work if you have a string called WS_New. I think you want to use Sheets("WS_New") if WS_New is the name of the sheet.

When you use WS_New.Cells, this time you are using the codename of the sheet.

Acceptable examples for a sheet named WS_New codenamed wsNewSheet.

```
Sheets("WS_New").Range("A1")
Sheets("WS_New").Cells(1,1)
wsNewSheet.Range("A1")
wsNewSheet.Cells(1,1)
```

[image]

In the above example, "Shell" is the name of the worksheet and "f_Shell" is its codename.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Destination:=Sheets(WS_New).Range(WS_New.Cells(1, 1).address, WS_New.Cells(LstRow2 - 1, LstCol2).address)
```

You are getting the "Type mismatch" because Excel uses the address for ranges, not the row/column format.  So when you type in

```
Destination:=Sheets(WS_New).Range(WS_New.Cells(1, 1), _ 
WS_New.Cells(LstRow2 - 1, LstCol2))
```

Excel is expecting to see:

```
Destination:=Range("A1:B1") format
```

By changing the notation from

```
Destination:=Sheets(WS_new).range(Ws_new.Cells(1,1), Ws_new.cells. (lstRow2-1, lstCol2)
```

to

```
Destination:=Sheets(WS_New).Range(WS_New.Cells(1, 1).Address, _ 
WS_New.Cells(LstRow2 - 1, LstCol2).address)
```

you will be sending Excel the format it is expecting.  the .address grabs the ("A1:B1") format that excel is lookijg for.

Comment: "While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so."