# VSTO Excel - How to create a range with multiple areas

Tags: c#, excel, range, vsto

If I have one or more ranges how can I combine them into a range with multiple areas?

One might think to do it like this... but this won't even compile...

```
Excel.Worksheet sheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
Excel.Range rng1 = (Excel.Range) sheet.get_Range(sheet.Cells[1, 1], sheet.Cells[3,42]);
Excel.Range rng2 = (Excel.Range) sheet.get_Range(sheet.Cells[5, 1], sheet.Cells[6,42]);
Excel.Range result = new Excel.Range();
result.Areas.Add(rng1);
result.Areas.Add(rng2);
```

UPDATE:

This is not a duplicate... this is about creating a range with two Areas... not about creating a range from two ranges each with a single cell (which would result in a range with only one area)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a range from 2 ranges in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527725/how-to-create-a-range-from-2-ranges-in-vba)

Comment: You should read the answers, aswell.

Comment: I see what you're talking about in the other answers... I'm not really sure if when the question is not about what you're asking and the accepted answer is not about what you're asking... if this should really be considered a duplicate... but I hear what you're saying... I will go ahead and type in an answer so that this question has a clear answer... and if it gets deleted by StackOverflow than so be it.

Comment: The reason, why I do believe its a duplicate is that you both are talking about 2 ranges and want to combine them to 1. It is totally irrelevant if the source ranges contains 1 cell or many cells. - In my opinion, its the same when you would say the question "How do I sum 1 + 2?" is different than "How do I sum 3 + 4?" and argument the difference with different numbers. FYI, StackOverflow wouldnt delete the question even if someone approved the flag, it would only be marked as duplicate. (Nothing "bad" will happen)

Comment: The only reason, why the accepted answer of the question I provided doesnt work for you is because its the most cheesy way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derived from one of the answers in the above referred to "duplicate" question.

Note: it seems if the areas can be combined a Union will do this (for example, two adjacent rows) but if they cannot be combined like this then it creates multiple areas. (not 100% sure on this)

Also, Union can have more than two parameters... e.g. Union(range1, range2, range3, etc...)

```
var excelApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application as Excel.Application;
var sheet = workbook.ActiveSheet as Excel.Worksheet;
var range1 = sheet.get_Range(sheet.Cells[1, 1], sheet.Cells[3,42]) as Excel.Range;
var range2 = sheet.get_Range(sheet.Cells[5, 1], sheet.Cells[6,42]) as Excel.Range;
var result = excelApp.Union(range1, range2) as Excel.Range;
```