# Concatenate Two Ranges by rows into one

Tags: excel, vba

So I am working on find values method in VBA currently for my project. The issue at hand right now is to figure out how I can concatenate two same size ranges into one. For example I have one range containing client First names and Second client Last names, the idea is that if the person is using app to search a client by first and last name then I can use one search value as First + Last name and search in one Range where Range_1 with First names is concatenated with Range_2 with Last names. I have written Find method which works for one search value and one lookup range, however if anyone could spare a simple example on how to concatenate two Ranges together by rows, that would be very helpful.

Below you can see my current find method, which works good. Also I'm total beginner so I am also looking for recommendations on how I can improve my code.

```
Sub SearchScenarioVar_1()

'The search Value'
Dim Var As String

'Search Range'
Dim RangeVar As Range

'Each Variable (total 3 variables) have been assigned one prime number (1, 3, 5),'
'SumOfVar represents sum value of filled in variables,'
'thus the filled in fields are known.'
Dim SumOfVar As String

'Based on value SumOfVar, X is 1, 2 Or 3'
Dim X As String

'XCol is column from Data table'
Dim XCol As Long

'LastRow is row from Data table'
Dim LastRow As Long

'XRow is row from variables'
Dim XRow As Long


'Used in Find method'
Dim FoundCell As Range
Dim FirstFoundCellAddress As String
Dim Found As String

'For displaying results'
Dim DataRow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'To clear fields where results will be displayed'
ClearInputCells3_1

'SumOfVar value fetched from app workbook'
SumOfVar = Workbooks("main_admin.xlsm").Sheets("main_admin").Range("C43").Value

'Assign X the value from 1 - 3 to know which search variable and search range to use in find method'
'1 & 2 are First and Last name, 3 is Social security number'
If SumOfVar = 1 Then
    X = 1
Else
    If SumOfVar = 3 Then
        X = 2
    Else
        If SumOfVar = 5 Or 6 Or 8 Or 9 Then
            X = 3
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End If
    
'Function to open the data table'
OpenDBclient
    
'Find last row in data table'
LastRow = Workbooks("main_data.xlsx").Sheets("data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Sets column and Row value for Find method'
XCol = 1 + X
XRow = 43 + X

'Fetches search value'
Var = Workbooks("main_admin.xlsm").Sheets("main_admin").Cells(XRow, 2).Value

'Sets search range'
Set RangeVar = Workbooks("main_data.xlsx").Sheets("data").Range(Cells(2, XCol), Cells(LastRow, XCol))

'DataRow is the First row where values will be displayed'
DataRow = 37

'Find Method starts'
With RangeVar
    Set FoundCell = .Find(What:=Var, After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
End With

If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
    FirstFoundCellAddress = FoundCell.Address
    Do
    'Writes values from data table to app displayed area'
    
    Found = Workbooks("main_data.xlsx").Sheets("data").Cells(FoundCell.Row, 1).Value
    Workbooks("main_admin.xlsm").Sheets("main_admin").Cells(DataRow, 87).Value = Found
    
    Found = Workbooks("main_data.xlsx").Sheets("data").Cells(FoundCell.Row, 2).Value
    Workbooks("main_admin.xlsm").Sheets("main_admin").Cells(DataRow, 63).Value = Found
    
    Found = Workbooks("main_data.xlsx").Sheets("data").Cells(FoundCell.Row, 3).Value
    Workbooks("main_admin.xlsm").Sheets("main_admin").Cells(DataRow, 69).Value = Found
    
    Found = Workbooks("main_data.xlsx").Sheets("data").Cells(FoundCell.Row, 4).Value
    Workbooks("main_admin.xlsm").Sheets("main_admin").Cells(DataRow, 75).Value = Found
    
    'Sets next row'
    DataRow = DataRow + 1
    
    Set FoundCell = RangeVar.FindNext(After:=FoundCell)
    
    'Sets limit to stop when the search has gone full circle or max row is reached'
Loop Until FoundCell.Address = FirstFoundCellAddress Or DataRow = 46
End If

'Closes data table'
CloseDBclient

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527725/how-to-create-a-range-from-two-ranges-in-vba

Comment: No need to concatenate the columns value. You can iterate between the rows of one column, but check the concatenation between this one and `Offset(0, 1).Value`.

Comment: Thank you for support the issue has been resolved